# importerror: no module named kwallet

Tags: python, py2exe

I was using py2exe trying to build a exe file for my python program when I received this error with the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "orchestrator.py", line 49, in <module>
import process_text as proc
File "process_text.pyc", line 14, in <module>
File "utilfuncs.pyc", line 5, in <module>
File "browsercookie\__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
File "keyring\__init__.pyc", line 6, in <module>
File "keyring\core.pyc", line 148, in <module>
File "keyring\core.pyc", line 64, in init_backend
File "keyring\util\__init__.pyc", line 20, in wrapper
File "keyring\backend.pyc", line 179, in get_all_keyring
File "keyring\backend.pyc", line 139, in _load_backends
File "keyring\backend.pyc", line 131, in _load_backend
File "importlib\__init__.pyc", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named kwallet
```

my main module (the one that contains the main) is called orchestrator.
my setup.py is like the following

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    console=['orchestrator.py'],
    options = {"py2exe":{"includes":["browsercookie"]}}
)
```

I am using windows 10 with python 2.7 
I did some digging but with no use. I did not find any exact or close matches to this error with py2exe. thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because py2exe cant dynamically locate "kwallet" module.

kwallet is located in "keyring.backends"

I had similar issue while using cx-freeze, I solved it by explicityly defining it.

For cx_freeze

```
packages=['atexit', "PySide", "jenkins", "packaging", 'client', 'keyring.backends.kwallet',
                               "keyring.backends.OS_X", "keyring.backends.SecretService",
                               "keyring.backends.Windows", "vulcantoolkit"]
```